# Changin data value using .data() and .attr() both failed

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="bca">
      <img width="60" height="35" class="brand img-responsive" alt="logo" 
        src="view/backoffice/assets/img/form-wizard/bca.png"
        data-src-retina="view/backoffice/assets/img/form-wizard/bca@2x.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

and I have this jquery :

```
$("#bri").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#bca").children().attr("src","view/backoffice/assets/img/form-wizard/bca-grey.png");
    $("#bca").children().attr("data-src-retina","view/backoffice/assets/img/form-wizard/bca-grey@2x.png");  
});
```

why I can't change `data-src-retina` value using jquery? I tried to use another method like this but also failed :

```
$("#bri").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#bca").children().attr("src","view/backoffice/assets/img/form-wizard/bca-grey.png");
    $("#bca").children().data("src-retina","view/backoffice/assets/img/form-wizard/bca-grey@2x.png");   
});
```

what did I do wrong here? thank you.

Comment: have you tried without using a diferent filename without `@`?

Comment: It does work...but you have the selector `#bri` when it should be `#bca` in your javascript.

Comment: @Amleonard : it's `#bri` because what I pasted here is shorten version of real codes

Comment: @FelipeMorales : I will try... thanks for the idea

Comment: @RobertHanson I thought that was possible. But when I put it in a fiddle it works. Do you know that the `click` event there is being executed at all?

Comment: Try to see if your code are inside $(document).ready()

Answer (score 1):

Seems your code works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bri").click(function() {
    $("#bca").children().each(function() {
      alert("Old data-src-retina:" + $(this).attr("data-src-retina"));
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#bca").children().attr("src", "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE9BlrARaNurkqQCh1Y-CeyvAsqpFYVVUwIe_TpPhhJLglGK0aRHZuZw");
    $("#bca").children().attr("data-src-retina", "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUc0zJ7TAI81eAL8sitUl81v409oihvi3fRfnnbyzTbhYAJC33");
    $("#bca").children().each(function() {
      alert("New data-src-retina:" + $(this).attr("data-src-retina"));
    });
  });
});
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mlyous7dosRl9IN9ds7U